# upper bound for equation

Tags: real-analysis

Let $0 < p < 1$ be some constant. I am looking for an $M$ such that

$$f(n) = \left(1-p^{\log{n}}\right)^{n} < M(n)$$

I am looking for a tight bound, something of the form: $2^{-n/\log{ n}}$. I checked in wolfram and it seems to go to $0$ when $n$ increases. I am looking for a bound in $n$.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I seem to remember that there is some relation with the exponential function, but I cannot find the appropriate bound...

Comment: I am curious as to how did this question come up? In what situation do you need such bound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $n$ is a positive integer, the bound would be 1. To see this, think about what happens when you take positive power of a number between $0$ and $1$. It will be again a number between $0$ and $1$.

Edit:
**The best bound in $n$ you can possibly get is $M(n)=1$.**
To see this, fix $p$ to be $0.1$. The limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n) = 1$. On the other hand, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n) = 0$ for $p=0.9$.

This is because $1-p^{\log x} = 1-e^{\log x \log p} = 1-e^{\log x^{\log p}} = 1-\frac{1}{x^{-\log p}}$:

- For $-\log(p)>1$, $f(n)$ goes to $0$ (as $n$ aproaches infinity)
- for $0<-\log(p)<1$, $f(n)$ goes to $1$ (as $n$ aproaches infinity)
- for $\log(p)=-1$, $f(n)$ goes to $1/e$ (as $n$ aproaches infinity).

These results can be obtained from the definition of $e$ as a limit of $(1+y)^{1/y}$,  where you take $y=1/x$.

If you allow your bounds to be a function in $p$ as well, you can take for example $M(n,p) = 1-p^{\log n}$, which is exceptionally poor bound for higher $n$. For $p$ such that $\log(p)>-1$, the best upper bound you can get is the maximum of $f$ which is achieved on $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually thinking of a much tighter bound something of the form 2^{-n/log(n)}

Comment: You want a *function* that bounds it then. 99% of the time, the notation that you use means a constant global bound, and that's usually the kind of bound one is interested in. If you want a *functional* bound, specify that.

Comment: I was considering the setting when p < 1/2, so it approximates 0. I was not really aware of this constraint. Sorry that I forgot to mention it. Could you tell me how you get that $1- \frac{1}{x^{-\log{p}}$ approaches 0 when x goes to infinity?

Comment: $1-\frac{1}{x^{-\log p}$ does NOT approach zero as x goes to infinity. It is $f_p(x)$ itself that goes to zero for p such that $-log(p)>1$.

Answer (score 0):

$1$ is an upper bound for obvious reasons.